# What is the difference between OnStart and the App Constructor

Tags: c#, xamarin, portable-class-library, xamarin.forms

Xamarin Forms has the following App class:

```
public class App : Application
{
        public App()
        {
            // The root page of your application
            MainPage = new ContentPage
            {
                Content = new StackLayout
                {
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    Children = {
                        new Label {
                            XAlign = TextAlignment.Center,
                            Text = "Welcome to Xamarin Forms!"
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        protected override void OnStart()
        {
            // Handle when your app starts
        }

        protected override void OnSleep()
        {
            // Handle when your app sleeps
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            // Handle when your app resumes
        }
}
```

**QUESTION:** What is the difference between the code that runs in the constructor and the code written in the OnStart method. Aren't both run when your application starts?

see http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/app-lifecycle/ for more information.

Comment: Constructors should be quick and not contain business logic (But that is a opinion so I am not posting it as the answer, there also may be a technical reason so I am not voting to close as "question is opinion based" either).

Comment: That's exactly my point. Is there a technical difference or is it just syntactical sugar for calling a method from the constructor?

Answer (score 3):

They are completely different however the documentation is less than sparse.

Constructors are platform-agnostic and for the purpose of creating the object (apologies if this sounds like 'teaching you to suck eggs').

The OnStart() method however is mapped to the platform specific notification and its relevant meaning. This is the cross-platform implementation of each varying operating systems start up notification system - this will of course be different between the platforms but this abstraction allows you to handle it in an identical fashion.

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer, it sounds logical. However can you think of a concrete difference? As far as I can reason.. both will execute at about the same point.

Comment: My two cents - I was somewhat surprised to find out that App constructor gets called also on Resume, which breaks my bootstrapping process because I assumed that there will always be only one single App instance from app creation till death (e.g. when Android or iOS kills the app during sleep).